# Hive User Impersonation

Tags: hadoop, hive, thrift, impersonation

I need some information on Hive user impersonation. I did some research on it and found that by default  HiveServer2 performs a query  processing as the user who submitted query but if `hive.server2.enable.doAs` set it to false then query will be run as user who started hiveserver2 process.

I need to a create jdbc/thirft connection with hiveserver2 with service account (let’s say with user ‘ABC’ is logged in) but would like to run my hive statement with user that I pass , for example with user ‘XYZ’.

Let me know if anyone has done this before.

Is it possible to do this for Hive ?

Comment: All JDBC connectors support **user / password** authentication. So what is your issue????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Hive impersonation enabled , you can run your queries that you will pass along with connection string .

For Example

jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default,username,password

In this case , your job will run with username that you are passing instead of hive user.

hope this helps.

Comment: Oddly this, using this in beeline prompts me for the username and password and then fails to connect; are you sure it's a comma? When using beeline I found the general format documented as: jdbc:hive2://<host1>:<port1>,<host2>:<port2>/dbName;initFile=<file>;sess_var_list?hive_conf_list#hive_var_list

setting ;user=hadoop still prompts for a user and password but the session variable seems to override the credentials provided if you use `current_user()`